# How to add reference in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I need to use all the classes in one project in another. I tried adding the references, clicked on the project tab but I can't see the `.cs` or `.sln` files or any other files, just the exe in the debug folder and the `.vshost` file and the manifest file.

What file do I need to reference in the project?

Comment: Maybe you need to Include those files in your project? Click on `Show All Files` on `Solution Explorer` and see which files are included or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File > Open > Project/Solution > Add to Solution (A little checkbox in the file dialog) then click the .sln you want

Comment: this adds the project to my current project, what happens when i compile release of my project? is the exe of the added project compiled too?

Comment: I don't think so. I think its only the solution files, .cs's , etc.

Answer (score 0):

Right mouse click on the project that needs a reference to another project --> Add Reference --> Click the checkbox(es) next to each project you wish to refer.

[image: Checkboxes and projects to refer to]

Once you have added your reference you will need to include the namespace "using NamespaceOfSecondProject" in the class that will use the referred project.

Answer (score -1):

You need to elaborate you question - Well why would you  want  to have redundant classes in two projects better build a class library and reference the dll in both the projects. If at all you need to include the classes from one project to another you simply need to copy the .cs file to other project and then select project and select add existing item then select the .cs file which you wanted to add. Hope this will help.